# Evaluating $F(a)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(an+1)(n+1)}$ for $a\geq0$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I am attempting to evaluate 
$$F(a)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(an+1)(n+1)},\qquad a\geq0$$
I was able to get thus far:
$$\begin{align}
F(a)&=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{an+1}\int_0^1x^n\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{an+1}x^n\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^nx^n\int_0^1t^{an}\mathrm dt\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\sum_{n\geq0}(-xt^a)^n\mathrm dt\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dt}{xt^a+1}\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\log(t^a+1)}{t^a}\mathrm dt
\end{align}$$
But I'm stuck on this integral. Could I have some help? Thanks.

Comment: When $a=\pm 1$, a closed form can be obtained easily by residue theorem. For other values of $a$, I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using partial fractions, this can be written as
  $$ \frac{\Psi\left(\frac{a+1}{2a}\right) - \Psi\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right) - 2 \ln(2)}{2(a-1)} $$
for $a \ne 0,\; 1$.  The value for $a=0$ is $\ln(2)$ and the value for $a=1$ is 
$\pi^2/12$.

EDIT: Here are more details.
The partial fraction decomposition is 
$$ \frac{1}{(an+1)(n+1)} = \frac{a}{(a-1)(an+1)} - \frac{1}{(a-1)(n+1)} $$
For the second term,
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} = \ln(2)$$
For the first, use $$\Psi(x) = -\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+x-1}\right)$$
so that 
$$ \eqalign{\Psi\left(\frac{a+1}{2a}\right) - \Psi\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k + 1/(2a)-1} - \frac{1}{k+1/(2a)-1/2}\right)\cr
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2a(-1)^n}{an+1}}$$
where the terms for even $n$ correspond to $1/(k+1/(2a)-1)$ and odd $n$ correspond to $-1/(k+1/(2a)-1/2)$.

Comment: Could you please provide a proof?